# API calls in batch class's start method

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch, callout, apexrest

Can we make API calls in 'start' method of batch class ?

Comment: What sort of API call? Your tagging suggests performing some form of callout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to do so, assuming you use [Database.AllowsCallouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) and you have no pending DML statements (e.g. you have not used insert/upsert/update/merge/delete/undelete/etc).